# Traer datos a formulario en PHP (AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax

estoy aprendiendo e intentando hacer un CRUD en PHP. La parte de insertar y borrar ya lo he logrado.
Al dar click en el boton AGREGAR, abre un MODAL con un formulario. (Funciona OK)
Al darle click al boton BORRAR, borra el campo seleccionado. (Funciona OK)

El problema lo tengo en la sección MODIFICAR. Cuando doy click abre el MODAL, pero no se como traer TODA LA INFORMACIÓN.

Este es el CRUD
[image: Este es el CRUD]

Esto sucede actualmente al darle EDITAR
[image: Esto sucede actualmente al EDITAR]

Pero si entro desde la URL pasandole el ID de esta forma:
http://localhost/php/agregar.php?id=11 ahi si me funciona correctamente y veo la información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para traer la información directamente a ese MODAL en la misma URL? (O sea http://localhost/php/agregar.php) Es con AJAX? Me estoy quemando la cabeza hace rato con esto y no logro sacarlo.

Una cosa más que quiero aclarar es que los codigos de INSERTAR, MODIFICAR y BORRAR funcionan corectamente. Cuando yo entro como dije antes desde:
http://localhost/php/agregar.php?id=11, edito el campo y doy ACTUALIZAR, lo modifica perfectamente.

Espero que se haya entendido la pregunta y perdon si no fue claro, cualquier cosa me dicen y trato de explicarlo.

Saludos

Comment: Sí, deberás usar Ajax para eso. Y ni siquiera necesitarías un modal. Puedes incorporar el formulario al mismo DOM que manda la petición y actualizarlo de forma dinámica. Es mucho más práctico y mucho mejor desde el punto de vista de la experiencia del usuario. Con Ajax los modales ya no son necesarios, es mucho mejor tener una interfaz totalmente integrada, a manera de un escritorio de trabajo, donde puedes ir mostrando / ocultando áreas si fuera necesario, que tener que estar abriendo/cerrando modales. Los modales son de la época de Windows 3, los años 90.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano por tu respuesta. Tienes algun link o algo que me sirva como referencia? Algo leí de AJAX, pero no se como traerle la informacion de mi archivo traerDatos.php que es justamente el que tiene la sentencia SQL con el ID a buscar. He mirado todo Google y sigo sin poder llegar a la solución de como obtenerlo y una vez obtenido pintarlo en cada campo del modal. Por otro lado, puede que sea antiguo, pero como dije estoy recién aprendiendo y para mi ya es todo un logro esto poco q hice jaja xD. Nuevamente gracias y espero tu respuesta.

Comment: Aquí en Stackoverflow hay varias preguntas con respuestas que explican cómo funciona Ajax, [aquí te dejo la lista de preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=votes&pageSize=50). Encontrarás sin duda varias de ellas que te ayudarán a comprenderlo. Cuando aprendas con Ajax te aseguro que todo irá sobre ruedas. Si tienes cualquier duda en concreto podremos ayudarte. El problema es que como está planteada tu pregunta no podemos partir de un problema concreto (sobre el código) para darte una solución.